# Part of String Case Insensitive in JavaScript Regex (?i) option not working

Tags: javascript, regex, case-insensitive

I am using Nodejs to build an application in which I need to process certain strings I have used the JS "RegExp" object for this purpose.
I want only a part of my string in the regex to be case insensitive

```
var key = '(?i)c(?-i)ustomParam';
var find = '\{(\\b' + key +'\\b:?.*?)\}';
var regex = new RegExp(find,"g");
```

But it breaks with following error

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /{(\b(?i)c(?-i)ustomParam\b:?.*?)}/

I will get the key from some external source like redis and the string to be matched from some other external source , I want that the first alphabet should be case-Insensitive and the rest of alphabets to be case-Sensitive.

When I get the key from external source I will append the (?i) before the first alphabet and (?-i) after the first alphabet.

I even tried this just for starters sake, but that also didn't work

```
var key ='customParam';
var find = '(?i)\{(\\b' + key +'\\b:?.*?)\}(?-i)';
var regex = new RegExp(find,"g");
```

I know I can use "i" flags instead of above ,but that's not my use case. I did it just to check.

Comment: You cannot make a _part_ of regex case-insensitve, use `i` flag on complete regex.

Comment: Bad news: even [XRegExp cannot offer this functionality](http://xregexp.com/syntax/), you can only use `(?i)` on the whole pattern declaring it at the pattern beginning. In XRegExp, you can define the regex as `var regex = XRegExp('(?i)\\{(\\b' + key +'\\b:?.*?)\\}', 'g');`

Comment: OKi so JavaScript regex library sucks.

@WiktorStribiżew if you had posted your comment as answer I would have accepted it as answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript built-in `RegExp` does not support *inline modifiers*, like `(?im)`, let alone inline modifier groups that can be placed *anywhere* inside the pattern (like `(?i:....)`).

Even [XRegExp cannot offer this functionality](http://xregexp.com/syntax/), you can only use `(?i)` on the whole pattern declaring it at the pattern beginning.

In XRegExp, you can define the regex ONLY as

```
var regex = XRegExp('(?i)\\{(\\b' + key +'\\b:?.*?)\\}', 'g');
```

On May 27, 2020, still neither JavaScript native RegExp, nor XRegExp patterns support inline modifier groups (i.e. `(?i:...)`), nor placing them in any part of the pattern (as far as XRegExp is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible starting from [Chrome 122](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5100254548721664) using [RegExp modifiers](https://tc39.es/proposal-regexp-modifiers/).

To enable a flag for a subexpression, use `(?X:subexpr)` where X is one of `i`, `m`, or `s`.
To disable a flag for a subexpression, use `(?-X:subexpr)`.

##### Enable a flag for part of regex:

```
const r1 = /^[a-z](?i:[a-z])$/;
r1.test("ab"); // true
r1.test("Ab"); // false
r1.test("aB"); // true
```

##### Disable a flag for part of regex:

```
const r2 = /^[a-z](?-i:[a-z])$/i;
r2.test("ab"); // true
r2.test("Ab"); // true
r2.test("aB"); // false
```

Comment: This is great news! Probably be a little while before it's production ready from a browser interop point of view though.