# Regular Expression regex works in PHP but fails with errors in JS

Tags: javascript, php, regex

**So I have this regular expression...**

`(?i)\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o]*(ffice)*\.*(?<=po|p.o|o\.|office|post)\s*[b][o][x]\b|(?<=\d\s|^)\s*[[b][o][x]]*(?!\s*[a-z])|(?<=\d\s|^)\s*[[p][o]]*(?!\s*[a-z])`

**If you look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CuBLCO/4) and run the unit tests in PHP you can see all the tests match.**

[image]

**However, that same regex fails in JS.**

[image]

Seems to be an issue with the first ? and possibly the use of look-backs?  I might as well be looking at Japanese.

Is there an easy way to make this regex compatible with JS?

Comment: Just use `i` flag in JS regex, no need to use the inline modifier that JS RegExp does not support.

Comment: I tried before to just take out the ? but the unit tests still fail, try and see.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CuBLCO/7

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew THANK YOU!  Your a genius! Sorry this was closed so fast, you deserve credit for an aswer!

Comment: But I [did answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37208514/3832970). Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript) is relevant