JavaScript Modifier: (?i:...) with nested x{n} Quantifier fails
This is not a duplicate of Part of String Case Insensitive in JavaScript Regex (?i) option not working . I already use the feature proposed in those answers and my question is about that feature.
We use a proprietary wrapper for javascript replaceAll that calls new RegExp(p, "g") and it doesn't support extra flags. So we started using local modifiers within the pattern string, but sometimes the "i" modifier behaves strangely. I managed to isolate this:


console.log(/(?i:[A-Z]{3})/.test("abcdefghijkl")); // returns true
console.log(/(?i:[A-Z]{4})/.test("abcdefghijkl")); // returns false 



meanwhile if "i" is used globally it works. I don't understand whether it's a bug in both Firefox and Chrome or my misunderstanding.

It appears to be related to the used quantifier - any value above 4 gets me false. Also, /^(?i:[ABCDEFGHIJKL]*)$/.test("abcdefghijkl") gives me false, with the quantifier changed into + it's true ... can't see any logic behind this, to me it looks like buggy implementation.

This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207947/part-of-string-case-insensitive-in-javascript-regex-i-option-not-working , whoever did that please read carefully

What happens if you remove the l from the end of the string? Do both return false?

It seems related also to the use of the character class, not just the quantifier, because the issue does not occur with /(?i:A{4})/.test("aaaaaaa"), but it does when using [A] instead of A. Yet [A] and A are identical patterns, so this clearly is a bug.

When I test in regex-101 matching are working perfectly: https://regex101.com/r/cZCx8r/1
But, JS Regex engine not working during validation: https://i.sstatic.net/f5OTHI36.png
This might be an issue

I thin there was another recent question (a week or 2 ago) where the size of the quantifier made a weird difference like this. I thought it was also about JS and (?<flags), but I can't find it in my search.

i've tried a litte bit.
My findings can be broken down into the following: 
It's true JS can is not able to understand (?i) it can only be used globally. Therefore:
console.log(/(?i:[A-Z]{3})/.test("abcdefghijkl")); 
// should return an error 
// or false if (?i) is ignored

console.log(/(?i:[A-Z]{4})/.test("abcdefghijkl")); // same here

If {x} is between 0 and 3 it returns true otherwise it returns false this is true for firefox nightly, firefox, brave, opera, chrome and edge.
The reason why I believe this is a bug:
After using safari it throws an error

Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?

Therefore I believe you are right this is a bug in chromium and firefox.
I hope this helps and if anything is unclear or incorrect please let me know! :)

Safari just throws an error because it has not implemented this new feature. It doesn't explain anything of the behaviour in Chrome / Firefox. You seem to miss this is syntax that is newly introduced with ECMAScript 2025.
